# jQuery popup on page load

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

At the moment,if I select an age and then click on a button,the age verification pop up comes up.But I would now want this popup to show before anything else on the site.

How can I make my age verification popup work on page load instead of having to click on a button first assuming that the min age is 18?

Here my pen so you can see: http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/ALYRwo
 here the js:

```
( function( $ ) {

     $(document) .ready(function(){ 
         alert(' Here it is');
        $.ageCheck = function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            minAge : 21,          
            redirectTo : '',
            redirectOnFail : '',
            title : 'Age Verification', 
            copy : 'This Website requires you to be [21] years or older to enter. Please enter your Date of Birth in the fields below in order to continue:'
        }, options);


        var _this = {
            month : '',  
            day : '',  
            year : '',   
            age : '',
            errors : Array(), 
            setValues : function(){
                var month = $('.ac-container .month').val();
                var day = $('.ac-container .day').val();
                _this.month = month; 
                _this.day = day.replace(/^0+/, ''); //remove leading zero
                _this.year = $('.ac-container .year').val();
            },
            validate : function(){
                _this.errors = [];
                if (/^([0-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])$/.test(_this.day) === false) {
                    _this.errors.push('Day is invalid or empty');
                };
                if (/^(19|20)\d{2}$/.test(_this.year) === false) {
                    _this.errors.push('Year is invalid or empty');
                };
                _this.clearErrors();
                _this.displayErrors();
                return _this.errors.length < 1;
            }, 
            clearErrors : function(){         
                $('.errors').html('');
            }, 
            displayErrors : function(){
                var html = '<ul>';
                for (var i = 0; i < _this.errors.length; i++) {
                    html += '<li><span>x</span>' + _this.errors[i] + '</li>';
                }
                html += '</ul>';
                setTimeout(function(){$('.ac-container .errors').html(html);},200);
            },
            reCenter : function (b){
                b.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - (b.outerHeight() + 150)) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
                b.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - b.outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
            }, 
            buildHtml : function(){

                var copy = settings.copy; 
                var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
                var html = '';
                html += '<div class="ac-overlay"></div>';
                html += '<div class="ac-container">';
                html += '<h2>' + settings.title + '</h2>';
                html += '<p>' + copy.replace('[21]','<strong>'+settings.minAge+'</strong>'); + '</p>';
                html += '<div class="errors"></div>';
                html += '<div class="fields"><select class="month">';
                for(var i=0;i<months.length;i++){
                    html += '<option value="'+i+'">'+months[i]+'</option>';
                }
                html += '</select>';
                html += '<input class="day" maxlength="2" placeholder="01" />';
                html += '<input class="year" maxlength="4" placeholder="1989"/>';
                html += '<button>Submit</button></div></div>';

                $('body').append(html);

                $('.ac-overlay').animate({
                    opacity: 0.8
                }, 500, function() {
                    _this.reCenter($('.ac-container'));
                    $('.ac-container').css({opacity: 1});
                });

                $(".ac-container .day, .ac-container .year").focus(function(){
                   $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
                });
            }, 
            setAge : function(){
                _this.age = '';                 
                var birthday = new Date(_this.year, _this.month, _this.day);  
                var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
                var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
                _this.age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
            }, 
            setSessionStorage  : function(key, val){
                try {
                    sessionStorage.setItem(key,val);
                    return true;
                } catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            handleSuccess : function(){                
                var successMsg = '<h3>Success!</h3><p>You are now being redirected back to the application...</p>';
                $('.ac-container').html(successMsg);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.ac-container').animate({'top':'-350px'},200, function(){
                         $('.ac-overlay').animate({'opacity':'0'},500, function(){
                            if (settings.redirectTo !== '') {
                                window.location.replace(settings.redirectTo);
                            }else{
                                $('.ac-overlay, .ac-container').remove();
                            }
                         });
                    });
                },2000);
            },
            handleUnderAge : function() {
                var underAgeMsg = '<h3>Sorry, you are not old enough to view this site...</h3>';
                $('.ac-container').html(underAgeMsg);
                if (settings.redirectOnFail !== '') {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.replace(settings.redirectOnFail);
                    },2000);
                }
            }
        }; //end _this

        if(sessionStorage.getItem("ageVerified") === "true"){
            return false;
        }

        _this.buildHtml();  

        $('.ac-container button').on('click', function(){
            _this.setValues();
            if (_this.validate() === true) {
                _this.setAge();

                if(_this.age >= settings.minAge){
                    if(!_this.setSessionStorage("ageVerified", "true")){
                        console.log('sessionStorage not supported by your browser');
                    };
                    _this.handleSuccess();
                }else{
                    _this.handleUnderAge();
                }
            }
        });

        $(window).resize(function() {
            _this.reCenter($('.ac-container'));
            setTimeout(function() {
                _this.reCenter($('.ac-container'));
            }, 500);
        });
    };
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="agecheck.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="jquery.agecheck.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                var minAge = $('select').val();
                $('select').on('change', function(){
                   minAge = $(this).val(); 
                });

                $('button').on('click', function(){
                    sessionStorage.clear();
                    $.ageCheck({minAge: minAge});
                });
                $.ageCheck({minAge: minAge});        
            });        
        </script>
        <style>
            .demo select {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 2px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            .demo h3 {
                font-family:'Bree Serif', arial; 
                font-weight:bold; 
                font-size:30px; 
                text-align:center; 
                border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;  
                padding:0 0 20px 0; 
                line-height:38px;
            }
            .demo p {

                font-family: georgia, serif; 
                font-size:18px; 
                line-height:26px; 
                text-align:center;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                color:#ADADAD;
            }
            .demo button {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                margin-top:5px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
                white-space: nowrap;
                vertical-align: middle;
                -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
                touch-action: manipulation;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
                background-image: none;
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                border-radius: 4px;
                padding: 4px 20px 6px 20px;
                font-size: 24px;
                line-height: 1.5;
                background:#8EB908;
                color:#fff; 
                text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #84A51D;
                 font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif; 
            }
            .demo button:hover{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background:#82A711;
            }
            @media (max-width: 500px) {
                .demo p {
                    font-size:12px;
                    line-height: 17px;
                }
                .demo h3 {
                    font-size:18px;
                    line-height:22px;
                }
                .demo button {
                    font-size:17px;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="demo">
        <h3>
            <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#666;" href="http://michaelsoriano.com/jquery-plugin-check-user-age/">AgeCheck.js <span style="color:red;">Demo</span><br>jQuery Plugin for Checking user age</a></h3>
            <div style="max-width:500px; padding:0; margin:0 auto;">
                <p>
                    AgeCheck.js will automatically prompt to check your age. It will redirect back to this page on success. You can change the minimum age by selecting from the select options, and 
                    re-trigger by clicking the big button below. 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Oh, the plugin is also responsive - so resize the viewport. Aitte?                 
                </p>               
                <p>
                    Minimum age:
                    <select name="age">
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button>Check My Age:</button>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Click <strong><a style="color:red" href="https://github.com/fearlessflyer/age-check">Here</a></strong> to go to the GitHub Repo.<br>
                    Click <strong><a style="color:red" href="http://michaelsoriano.com/jquery-plugin-check-user-age/">Here</a></strong> to go to the Documentation.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Seems to work for me, when I go to your page I get the age popup.

Comment: @neuhaus.weird. You mean the pop up comes up without you having to click on the button?Did you test that from my pen?

Comment: Yes. On Firefox 49 and Chrome 54 on Linux the popup asking for my birthdate appears rightaway.

Comment: I see.Problem is that this popup only comes up once in a ''life time''.Trying to make it work on page load

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971615/difference-between-pageload-onload-document-ready - perhaps you need to use a different event callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your function inside

> $(window).load(function() {})

This function will show popup before rendering.

[This might help you](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Opening-A-Popup-Window-On-Page-load/)

Comment: Mind showing me where/how from the pen I have?
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/ALYRwo?editors=1010

Comment: Just did the job for you, assuming that you have no prior knowledge of Bootstrap. http://codepen.io/shudhpandit/pen/PGLbad

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternate code from here.

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('#pop-up-content').firstVisitPopup({
cookieName : 'homepage',
showAgainSelector: '#show-message'
});
});
</script>
```